# Закрыть вкладки в Хроме

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Как автоматически закрыть вкладки хрома, соответствующие некому шаблону? Хотелось бы ещё при этом сохранить список адресов закрытых вкладок.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать своё расширение или открыть в режиме отладки любое расширение, имеющее доступ к адресам открытых вкладок (по умолчанию хром предоставляет доступ к `chrome.tabs`, но не к их адресам - для этого надо явно запросить в манифесте `"tabs"`). Далее выполняем такой код, предварительно поместив в `PATTERN` нужную регулярку:

```
var PATTERN = /^(view-source:)?https?:\/\/localhost[:/]/

chrome.tabs.query({}, tabs => {
  var toRemove = tabs.filter(t => t.url.match(PATTERN))
 
  if (!toRemove.length) return console.log("Nothing to close")

  var wnd = window.open()
  var text = [PATTERN, new Date().toLocaleString(), "", ...toRemove.map(t => t.url), ""].join("\n")
  wnd.document.write(`<a href="${URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([text]))}" download="Closed tabs.txt">download</a><plaintext>${text}`)

  chrome.tabs.remove(toRemove.map(t => t.id), () => {
    console.log(`Closed ${toRemove.length} tabs`)
    wnd.document.close()
    wnd.document.querySelector("a").click()
  })
})
```